# How would I generate random numbers ranging from -9 to 9?

Tags: java

```
        double random1 = Math.random() * 9 + -9;
        double random2 = Math.random() * -9 + 9;
```

I need randomly generated numbers ranging from -9 to 9 using Math.random. When I use this code I have here it only prints the first number as a negative number.I've ran this multiple times and still the first number is always negative while the second is positive. How can I fix this to be more random? Thanks

Comment: determine the length of result space (from `-9` to `9`), multiply the random value by this length, subtract the lower bound of the result space.

Comment: While asking questions you should get list of potentially related questions. One of them should be [How do I generate random integers within a specific range in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/363681) (taken from list called `Related` at right side of this page). Did you visit it?

Comment: Always **search Stack Overflow** before posting.

Answer (score 2):

Math.random() generates a number between 0 and 1.

How about multiplying by 18 and then subtracting 9?

Answer (score 1):

From jdk-7 you can use `ThreadLocalRandom`

**public int nextInt(int origin, int bound)**

> Returns a pseudorandom int value between the specified origin (inclusive) and the specified bound (exclusive).

```
ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(-9, 10) // will generate from -9>=x<10
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want a value between a number `min` and a number `max` :

```
Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1) + min
```